# How to build Google tink library using bazel in C++?

Tags: c++, bazel, tink

I want to use Google `tink` library for my app. I bound my code using android `ndk`. However, I couldn't build Google `tink` library with `bazel`. I have tried their examples on GitHub (https://github.com/google/tink). Moreover, I don't have any experience with `bazel`. Hence, if anyone knows how to build Google `tink` library in any way I am open to those options too.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Bazel 3.1.0
- gcc verion is 9.3.0

I have tried to follow https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/examples/cc/helloworld/README.md but it resulted in an error:

```
bazel build ...

Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: error loading package 'javascript/aead/internal': Unable to find package for @npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl: The repository '@npm' could not be resolved.
INFO: Elapsed time: 6.455s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded)
    currently loading: javascript/binary ... (6 packages)
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/examples/cc/helloworld/README.md

Comment: "I am failing to build google tink library with bazel." - Please, update the question post with the description of what actually have you **tried** and with **exact error message** you got.

Comment: I edited my question. You can check it thank you.

Comment: @Savrona: Please note, that on Stack Overflow the question is not a "chat". It is perfectly allowed to edit the question, but after each edit the question should be **complete** and understandable without reading the comments. I have edited your question and incorporated the link to README into it. If in the current form the description in the question post contradicts your intentions, then feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `README.md` was written, the entire project was in a single [Bazel workspace](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#workspace). Nowadays the `examples` subdirectory is it's own separate workspace, so you need to `cd` into it before executing `bazel`.

Correct instructions:

```sh
# Build the code.
git clone https://github.com/google/tink
cd tink/examples/cc
bazel build ...

# Create some input.
echo "some plaintext" > foo.txt

# Encrypt.
./bazel-bin/helloworld/hello_world ./helloworld/aes128_gcm_test_keyset_json.txt \
    encrypt foo.txt "some aad" foo.encrypted

# Decrypt.
./bazel-bin/helloworld/hello_world ./helloworld/aes128_gcm_test_keyset_json.txt \
    decrypt foo.encrypted "some aad" foo-decrypted.txt

# Inspect the output.
cat foo-decrypted.txt
```

Note, [the C++ implementation also supports using CMake](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/CMAKE-HOWTO.md), which may be easier to ramp up with for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you. Your instructions helped me to build the examples with bazel  and as you said cmake is better for me.  Indeed I manage to build it with cmake somehow. But I don't know why it gives bad std::bad_alloc when I try ```auto  status = crypto::tink::TinkConfig::Register();``` or ```auto status = crypto::tink::AeadConfig::Register();```.

Comment: It's difficult to help without more context (i.e. your code and how you're building it). Feel free to ask another question or open an issue in the GitHub repo.